# Make some inserts in Mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert 3 words in a database but I only insert the last one, I would like to insert the 3 words each one in a different raw.

```
import MySQLdb
bd = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","welcome","mydb")

cursor = bd.cursor()
palabras = ["hola", "python", "pythondiario"]
for i in palabras:
     sql = "insert into empresa (codigo_unico) values ('%s')" % (i)


#cursor.execute(sql)


bd.commit()
bd.close()
```

it only insert pythondiario in a raw, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not executing the SQL in the loop.

Comment: You should put `cursor.execute` inside the loop

Comment: Thank you, I really apreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Just because you didnt execute your query inside loop only the query for the last element of list will be executed , put `cursor.execute(sql)` inside loop:

```
cursor = bd.cursor()
palabras = ["hola", "python", "pythondiario"]
for i in palabras:
     sql = "insert into empresa (codigo_unico) values ('%s')" % (i)
     cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Thank you, I really apreciate your help

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helps you, please accept my answer to better understanding for future users